# Error while running ESLint: Cannot read property 'range' of null

Tags: node.js, eslint

I am getting a super annoying eslint error when using an IDE (atom or VS code) on my mac.

[image: 1]]

Its a web app, react front-end & node backend. The package manager is npm.

It feels like every now and then eslint flips out and wastes my time for afew hours at a time (it has happened before).

Update:

I am using ES6 syntax & babel.

Update 2 (fix):

```
rm -rf node_modules
```

remove this line from .eslintrc

```
"parser": "babel-eslint",
```

MAKE SURE atom (or whatever IDE you are using) shows you this error:

[image: 2]]

Now add the line you removed back to .eslintrc:

```
"parser": "babel-eslint",
```

and run

```
npm i
```

Now eslint should work again

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to `import` something is:

```
import { Something, SomethingElse } from 'somewhere';
```

If you need to import express, you have to use `require`. It seems like you want to import `express` itself and `router`, so the correct syntax will be:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
```

Comment: Sorry, I left out atleast one piece of information that is important, its ES6 syntax

Comment: `import DefaultName, { ExportName1, ExportName2, ... } from 'module-name';` is [valid ES6 `import` syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import)

Comment: I agree. Its something weird with babel-eslint I think.

Comment: I believe it had errors for both backend & front-end code (error is gone now so I cannot double check). The error existed on multiple files.

Comment: Express is a backend technology, so you can easilly `require` it as I described in my answer.